# className changes in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, classname

I have a component which should have css animation it's very easy to make it with simple className changing.
Should I go for this solution or it's not correct in redux and I need to trigger action to change className?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's simple, go for it!

I suggest that you read it: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367#.ci8uyhdm9

> If you feel pressured to do things “the Redux way”, it may be a sign that you or your teammates are taking it too seriously. It’s just one of the tools in your toolbox, an experiment gone wild.

Comment: Thx, for sharing your thoughts, appreciate it!